# Project created by libgdx is not working on android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, libgdx, adt

I am using the latest libgdx version (0.9.9) and latest version of ADT (Build: v22.6.2-1085508) with SDK Tolls version 22.6.2 and SDK platform-tools version 19.0.1 and SDK Build version 19.0.3. my program runs fine on Desktop but when i want to emulate it on android it gives me error(unfortunately, BirdEscape has stopped). My desktop is 64bit and I have **armeabi** and **armeabi-v7a** in root directory of android. please look at here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cdogyhbxj3x8kyh/Capture.PNG

setting for device is this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ogk7hlv5oeat036/capturesetting.PNG

```
04-25 18:14:18.383: D/dalvikvm(1198): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.Solijon.BirdEscape.android-1/libgdx.so 0xb3d03bb8
04-25 18:14:18.423: D/dalvikvm(1198): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.Solijon.BirdEscape.android-1/libgdx.so 0xb3d03bb8
04-25 18:14:18.423: D/dalvikvm(1198): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.Solijon.BirdEscape.android-1/libgdx.so 0xb3d03bb8, skipping init
04-25 18:14:18.503: D/AndroidRuntime(1198): Shutting down VM
04-25 18:14:18.503: W/dalvikvm(1198): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a3fba8)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198): Process: com.Solijon.BirdEscape.android, PID: 1198
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Solijon.BirdEscape.android/com.Solijon.BirdEscape.android.AndroidLauncher}: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Libgdx requires OpenGL ES 2.0
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Libgdx requires OpenGL ES 2.0
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.createGLSurfaceView(AndroidGraphics.java:121)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(AndroidGraphics.java:101)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(AndroidGraphics.java:94)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.init(AndroidApplication.java:130)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.initialize(AndroidApplication.java:96)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at com.Solijon.BirdEscape.android.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:14)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-25 18:14:18.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically LibGDX is erroring as the emulator isnt allowing it to use GLES 2. To enable that on the emulator you need to tick the "Use host GPU" box in its set up.